# Can't get birthday from Google Contacts Data API in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am trying to get a user's contact's birthdays, from Google's data API using the gdata gem. But even though I use the full feed, it does not include the gContact:birthday element.

I have also tried fetching only one contact, but the birthday element is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the ruby library has not been upgraded to use the version 3 protocol... Damn...